# Implementing a three-valued logic operation with Boolean operators?

Tags: java, logic

I've created an enum class Proposition with three possible constants,

```
public enum Proposition {

    TRUE, FALSE, NULL;

}
```

and I'd like to make it so that, when I write code using Boolean operators

```
Proposition propA = Proposition.FALSE;

Proposition propB = Proposition.NULL;

Proposition propC = propA && propB;
```

propC would become NULL, following Kleene's logic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

How would I implement that in Java? Do I HAVE to use a method or can I use Boolean operators?

Comment: You can't override operators in Java, so no. You can use Boolean, which does represent the tri-state, but your null case won't work as you expect.

Comment: Meaning I can't use operators for custom classes in general, right?

Comment: **"I can't use operators for custom classes in general"** — yes, java doesn't have operator overloading. Instead you'd have to define methods in your `Proposition` class, like `Proposition Proposition::and(Proposition other)`.

Comment: Right. Some languages let you define custom semantics for any operator in your own classes. [In C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), they use `<<` which is a operator designed to do bitshifting, to let you write to stdout more easily `std::cout << "print me";`. It's useful for matrix multiplication `matrix1 * matrix2` and loads of other things. Java doesn't have that feature though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement this yourself using enum methods (something like what we get from `Predicate`); operators can't be overridden in Java. Here's an example:

```
enum Proposition {
    TRUE(Boolean.TRUE),
    FALSE(Boolean.FALSE),
    NULL(null) {
        @Override
        public Proposition and(Proposition other) {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Proposition or(Proposition other) {
            return this;
        }
    };

    private final Boolean value;
    Proposition(Boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Proposition and(Proposition other) {
        if (NULL == other) return NULL;
        return of(this.value && other.value);
    }
    public Proposition or(Proposition other) {
        if (NULL == other) return NULL;
        return of(this.value || other.value);
    }

    public static Proposition of(Boolean bool) {
        return null == bool ? NULL : (bool ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }
}
```

And here's the call corresponding to your example:

```
Proposition propA = Proposition.FALSE;
Proposition propB = Proposition.NULL;

Proposition propC = propA.and(propB);
System.out.println(propC); // NULL
```

In other words, call `.or()` method for `||` and `.and()` method for `&&`.

Comment: I know very little about enums, how would I use this?

Comment: Will add example calls, @SimoneTarenzi

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for.